# Basic properties of Riesz spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, vector-lattices

I'm self studyhing from Peter Meyer-Nieberg's Banach Lattices,  and I'm having some trouble with some of the very basic properties.  So,  what I have to work with at this point is the definition:  We have a vector space E with a partial-order lattice (so all pairs have a sup and an inf).,   such that addition of by a fixed vector and multiplication by nonnegative real scalars is preserved by the operation.

So, in his theorem 1.1.1 (i), he asserts that $\forall x,y,z\in E$, 
 $$x+y=x\lor y+x\land y$$
$$x\lor y=-((-x)\land (-y))$$
$$x\lor y+z=(x+z)\lor(y+z)$$
$$x\land y+z=(x+z)\land (y+z)$$

The second one seems to be the usual inverse of a sup becomes the inf of the inverses, but does that automatically hold with an arbitrary space with just the Riesz properties listed above?   For his proof, he defines $$w=(-y)\lor (-x)$$
$$v=x\lor y$$
and proceeds to show that $$w+x+y\ge v$$
I followed those steps,  but I didn't see how that immediately gives the rest of the results claimed.   I know later on he says that we will prove that all finite equality and inequality statements in a Riesz space holds if and only if the statement holds for real numbers,  but we haven't gotten to that point yet.

Answer (score 1):

You want to show that
$$
x\wedge y = - ((-x)\vee (-y))
$$
So check that
$$
x \leq x\wedge y \Rightarrow -(x\wedge y) \leq -x
$$
and similarly with $y$ on the RHS. Hence
$$
-(x\wedge y) \leq (-x)\vee (-y) 
$$
And for the reverse inequality, suppose
$$
-x \geq z \text{ and } -y\geq z \Rightarrow -z \geq x \text{ and } -z \geq y
$$
and hence
$$
-z \geq x\wedge y \Rightarrow -(x\wedge y)\geq z
$$
Hence, $-(x\wedge y)$ is the infimum of the set $\{-x,-y\}$.